# How to send multiple images Amazon S3 Server ios objective-c

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images to Amazon S3 using this logic:

```
- (void)uploadImageToS3: (UIImage *)image {
  imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);

  AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
  getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = @"dummyimages";
  getPreSignedURLRequest.key = @"test.jpg";

  getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodPOST;
  getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

  NSString *fileContentTypeString = @"text/plain";
  getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = fileContentTypeString;

  [[[AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder defaultS3PreSignedURLBuilder] getPreSignedURL:getPreSignedURLRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    } else {

        NSURL *presignedURL = task.result;
        NSLog(@"upload presignedURL is \n%@", presignedURL);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:presignedURL];
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
        [request setValue:fileContentTypeString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Upload errer: %@", error);
            }
            NSLog(@"Done");
        }];

        [uploadTask resume];
    }

    return nil;

 }];
}
```

I am getting an error like this:
*'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method*.

could please help this issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html , in the section *Preparing iOS 9 Apps*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure your service configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) in the class that is responsible for managing the Amazon Identity.

If you are using the newer version of [MobileHub](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-mobile-hub-build-test-and-monitor-mobile-applications/) then the AWS constants 
are configured in your info.plist and you need to check this

If you are using an older version MobileHub then the constants file is AWSConfiguration.

The class responsible for managing identity is AWSIdentityManager where the function that configures the service is

```
- (AWSTask *)initializeClients:(NSDictionary *)logins
```

If you are not using MobileHub you need to implement something similar in your own identity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code line for info.Plist file

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```